# Can I create my own function with the same name as an existing to customize it?

Tags: javascript

I have some console.log commands spread through my site.

Is it possible to override console.log with my own function?  I want to customize the function so that it only logs if a specific variable is set to true.

In the end, I would still need to call the real console.log from this function.

Thanks
Kevin

Comment: It might have been quicker to just try it.

Comment: JavaScript is nothing but yet another programming language. It should support overriding.

Comment: @UmeshA That's a bad assumption. PHP, for example, does not allow overriding functions. Function overriding is a concept that is hard to get in some languages, especially native ones where a function name is converted to a location by the compiler.

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/yzsHE/) what you want ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create a closure, and store the original `console.log` function in a local variable.
Then override `console.log`, and call the original function after you do your check:

```
(function(){
    var original = console.log;

    console.log = function(){
        if ( log ) { // <-- some condition
            original.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    };
})();
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/J46w8/

Comment: Nicely done. I wonder, though, what the `this` parameter for `console.log` is supposed to be... perhaps the `window` object? Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: @voithos - `this` would be the `console` object, since it's being called as its method. [See here](http://jsfiddle.net/EbjPV/).

Comment: Ah, right. Silly me. _But_, if that is so, then you really should be sending `console` in your `.apply()`. Here's an update to your fiddle that shows that `this` isn't the console object, in your new function: [http://jsfiddle.net/voithos/J46w8/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/voithos/J46w8/1/)

Comment: @voithos - It sure is, [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/J46w8/2/). You `alert` the `console` object, which is the same as calling `alert( console.toString() )`, which gives you `[object Object]`.

Comment: Woah, that is odd - I was basing myself off Chrome's dev tools. I tried doing `alert(console);`, and it displayed `[object Console]`. I guess that's because the native console is different from a JavaScript implementation (i.e. Firebug Lite). My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Save the old `console.log()` first.

```
var reallog = console.log;
console.log = function(s) {
    if(s == "a") {
        reallog("a");
    }
}
console.log("b");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
console.constructor.prototype.log = function(msg) {
    alert(msg);
};
```